# apt-get hang at Rsyslog

Tags: apt, apparmor

When I try to install something, there is a hang, I don't know if it's a bug or something else...

```
root@computer:~# apt-get install
Reading package list... Done
Building dependancy tree
Reading state information... Done
The following package has been automatiquelly installed but aren't necessary :
  libtext-glob-perl libfile-find-rule-perl libnumber-compare-perl
Please use « apt-get autoremove » to remove them
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove.
Paramating rsyslog (5.8.6-1ubuntu8.3) ...
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
```

And it's hanging there.  I let it run for more then 15 minutes, I had to stop it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

*Anyone has an idea of how to fix it and/or what may be the cause?*

Comment: Try `apt-get update && apt-get install -f && apt-get autoremove` post any errors.

Comment: I did what you asked, there is no error.  It just stop at this line : Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd

Comment: Yes, you were not able to remove the package because dpkg thought it was started. Now try manually run "stop rsyslog", kill that script (you dont have to wait 5 minutes.. 5 sec is enough), then proceed with uninstalling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run `ps afx|grep rsyslog` in a different console, then:

1. If there are traces of rsyslogd running, probably in `<defunct>` state, this is a bug in the upstart scripts incompatibility which has been fixed. Simply `stop rsyslog`, upgrade to the recent version (`dpkg -r --ignore-depends rsyslog rsyslog && aptitude update && aptitude upgrade rsyslog`).
2. If there are **no** traces of rsyslogd running, and the only related process that hangs is `start rsyslog`, you need to reboot (and then perhaps continue with step 1).

Comment: Hi Ilya Semenov, I tried what you said, please see my edit for the log.  Thx

Comment: Thx!  It worked!  Stoping the service then suppressing the package worked very well!