# rsyslogd hangs upon apt-get 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, rsyslog

If I do any apt-get install, it hangs permanently (have to CTRL-Z, CTRL-C does nothing) and then corrupts dpkg (have to run dpkg --configure etc) and I have to kill all rsyslog related processes. I've seen issues like this mentioned on rsyslog5.28 but I'm running 7.4.4-ubuntu2.5.

This prevents me from installing or upgrading any packages. Any ideas? TIA.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.1 on GCE Image.

3.16.0-29-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 20:54:13 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Here's what I'm left with

```
syslog   24545  0.0  0.0 274636  3216 ?        Ssl  07:33   0:00 rsyslogd
root     25702  0.0  0.0  15312  4212 pts/1    Ss+  07:42   0:00 /usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 26 --configure rsyslog:amd64
root     25703  0.0  0.0   4452  1556 pts/1    S+   07:42   0:00 /bin/sh                 /var/lib/dpkg/info/rsyslog.postinst configure 7.4.4-1ubuntu2.3
root     25810  0.0  0.0   4452  1572 pts/1    S+   07:42   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d rsyslog restart
root     25839  0.0  0.0  16896  2316 pts/1    S+   07:42   0:00 start rsyslog
```

sumeet   25863  0.0  0.0  10476  2176 pts/0    S+   07:43   0:00 grep --color=auto     rsyslog

Here is a sample command I issue:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
rsyslog
Suggested packages:
rsyslog-mysql rsyslog-pgsql rsyslog-doc rsyslog-gnutls rsyslog-gssapi
rsyslog-relp    
The following NEW packages will be installed:
rsyslog
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 355 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,578 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://gce.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main rsyslog amd64 7.4.4-1ubuntu2.5 [355 kB]
Fetched 355 kB in 1s (334 kB/s)  
Selecting previously unselected package rsyslog.
(Reading database ... 48585 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../rsyslog_7.4.4-1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rsyslog (7.4.4-1ubuntu2.5) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up rsyslog (7.4.4-1ubuntu2.5) ...
The user `syslog' is already a member of `adm'.
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall rsyslog` and then try again.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Trying @heemayl's advise I get:
`E: Internal Error, No file name for rsyslog:amd64`

Comment: try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Here is a solution that worked for me:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/310210/apt-get-hang-at-rsyslog?rq=1

Comment: Looks like this is a *really* big problem:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/1417037